# How to progress through event gateway using Activiti REST API

Tags: java, rest, activiti

I have a process where, at some point, two different kind of message can occurs, and if none appears after a time, the workflow goes timeout.

Based on the documentation, I have modelised the process using a event gateway :

[image]

To progress my activiti workflow, I am using activiti REST API. However, I cannot find in the documentation how to send a message to the gateway in order to continue to either Message 1 or Message 2. I tried triggering message to all execution IDs linked to my process ID but to no avail.

What is the right REST API command to progress in this workflow ?

Thanks for your support.

**Edit 1 :**

It seems that the Event Gateway is subbed to only one event.
It react to :

```
POST http://localhost:8082/activiti-rest/service/runtime/executions/20178
{"action":"messageEventReceived","messageName":"Message 1"}
```

and continue the process for the Message 1. However, with Message 2 defined exactly the same (but with another message), it returns the not found subscription error :

```
Execution with id '20178' does not have a subscription to a message event with name 'Message 2'"
```

Comment: Can you provide bpmn definition to reproduce the error you are getting ?

Comment: Even better reproduce the issue in the jUnit test. (template https://github.com/Activiti/activiti-unit-test-template)

Answer (score 0):

For an event gateway (https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnEventbasedGateway). The intermediate message/signal catching events are mutually exclusive. It will follow only one path from the gateway depending on which message is received. In your case, you have fired message 1 already, so the execution continues on message 1 path and other message subscriptions are deleted. Therefore you are getting the error.